# Tried to install Ubuntu. It failed. Now I'm at a GRUB screen. What is this and how do I resolve it?

Tags: boot, grub2

I just built my computer. Brand new everything. I tried to install ubuntu. I filled out the screen that asks you to assign a name to the computer, create a password, etc. When tried to continue, the screen said that I had an "unofficial copy" of ubuntu. What did I do wrong.

Now when I put a usb in the screen is black and says GNR GRUB version 2.02 at the top. What do I do from here? I've been Googling all day and have gotten nowhere. I tried boot-repair-disc and nothing happened.

Comment: Does the computer have any other operating systems on it?  Where did you get Ubuntu?  Also, please outline the specs a bit more.  We can get this solved.

Comment: Where did you download Ubuntu?

Comment: Yeah i ran into a problem like this when i was installing Ubuntu . How did You download the ubuntu iso If you did a direct download i would suggest download it from a torrent instead

Comment: I downloaded it from the Ubuntu website. What specs, specifically?

Comment: I also tried downloading it from a torrent.

Comment: No other OS exists on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to repeat from the beginning.
Try the first answer in here: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Especially the first 7 steps or so may solve your problem. If you think you did everything there right and used the official download source and the downloaded iso was not damaged, maybe an other answer here can help you.

Note that you eventually have to call the boot manager with pressing F11 or DEL while booting to select your usb boot device and start installation, instead of booting into your broken installation. *(**Note:** This is what helped the questioner. See comments.)*

To assure a correct download, you can use a bittorrent downloader application to download the iso. This is especially useful if you have a slow or unreliable internet connection. You can find the .torrent files for ubuntu here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Comment: The problem is that when I try to use a usb, it just takes me to the GRUB page. I think that if I could get past this I could restart but at the moment, restarting seems impossible.

Comment: So you tried putting in your usb drive and used the bios/uefi boot manager (most times pressing F11 or DEL while starting) to select the usb and there still comes the grub page?

Comment: I'll try it while pressing F11 or Del while starting it up. Will report results.

Comment: Oh my god it worked. Thank you so much. Everything's working great.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. I added this detail into my answer. Please accept it (if it worked), so other people can see which answer solved your problem. (You can click on a small round grey button on the left side of this question to accept it.) Thanks.